# Customize class name of generated jooq enum

Tags: enums, code-generation, jooq

I'm using jooq 3.18 and I would like to generate enum classes but with a prefix or postfix to avoid name clashing in my project.

Is it possible to customize to the generation of enums?

I'm aware of [custom code generators](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-enum-converter/) but I need a solution for all enums, without explicitly specifying a type and a specific generator.

Answer (score 0):

You're not looking for enum converters, which allow for converting between some database type to a custom enum type.

You're looking for generator strategies, e.g.

- [Programmatic](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/)
- [Configurative](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/)

Maybe, this will suffice?

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <strategy>
      <matchers>
        <enums>
          <enum>
            <expression>MY_ENUM</expression>
            <enumClass>
              <transform>CAMEL</transform>
              <expression>PREFIX_$0</expression>
            </enumClass>
          </enum>
        </enums>
      </matchers>
    </strategy>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```